# White Screen issue with Electron/Node app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I've recently created an app with a Java backend and a React frontend, and I was using Electron and some Node features to bundle the app and create a desktop app for it. Basically, I decided to use Java for some Java-specific libraries I needed. The app will run on port 8080, with the React/JS stuff being served from the static folder, and the Electron wrapper will use some Node libraries to start up the Java process and then after a few seconds connect to localhost:8080.

This works like a charm about half the time, and the other half instead shows me a white screen with no errors! I have debugged this countless times and the only way to fix it is to force reload the Chromium page which sometimes works, and other times doesn't. Obviously this isn't acceptable for users to do with my app. The problem is, I have run out of ideas as to what could be causing this issue.

Here is my main.js for the electron app

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
    try {
        var jarPath = './app.jar';
        var kill  = require('tree-kill');
        var child = require('child_process').spawn('java', ['-jar', jarPath, '']);
        let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 730});
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/index.html');
        }, 2000);
        console.log("PID: " + child.pid);
        win.on('closed', function () {
                kill(child.pid);
                mainWindow = null
            }
        )
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex to host on java and serve via electron (Defeats the entire purpose of having electron). Also using `setTimeout` in a production application for this purpose is quite crude. Your error most likely lies exactly there. The java server might not yet be running when you navigate to localhost. Maybe listen on `process.stdout` of your java application for a `ready` and only then navigate to localhost instead of via timeout